# How to import a matrix of integers from MATLAB?

Tags: import, matlab

I am importing a matrix from MATLAB. However, there are some redundant items added in the imported matrix.

For example, the imported matrix is a binary matrix. After import, it looks like this

```
{{{{{0, 1, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
  0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
  0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`,
  0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
  0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
  0.`}, {1.`, 0.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
  0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
  0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
  1.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
  0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
  0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`},......}}}}};
```

How can I get rid of `.` and `` ` ``?

There are some additional brackets also. However, the brackets are not an important issue.

The dimension is found to be {1, X, Y}. Where does this 1 come from?

Comment: What command do you use for importing? the leading 1 in the dimensions is probably from there. Please give the details.

Comment: I am using Import?

Comment: By "details" I mean write down the command with all options. Otherwise the reader needs to guess that you've used `Import` with no further options. The easier you make it for the reader, the better your chances of getting help.

Comment: Import["C:\Users\dipak\Desktop\data.mat"]

Comment: Matlab does not know integers. First axiom of Matlab: _Everything is a matrix of doubles (machine precision real numbers)._

Comment: The `"MAT"` file contains a list of saved variables.  That comes from MATLAB.  In your case, only one variable has been saved, which is why the dimensions `{1, X, Y}` begin with `1`.  In general, I would expect the dimensions to be `{n}`, where `n` is the number of variables.  Only if all variables are the same size arrays would you get `{n, X, Y}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Round[data]
```

> {{{{{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>        0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
>         1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, ...}}}}

Or `Round[First[data]]` to get rid of the first dimension of length 1.